# Logitech C920 camera keeps freezing

Tags: 12.04, drivers, kernel, usb, camera

Everytime using this camera it crash my system and gets unblessing freez. But when use Windows it works.

Why Ubuntu it crash and freez? Its a USB camera logitech C920?

How can i solve this?

http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Webcams/C920-driver-for-Ubuntu-VersionX-Fedora-VersionX-or-ArchLinux/m-p/849876

Problem is that:

This camera auto mount as random 
/dev/video1 or video0 it creates. So my patch is creating a static /dev/video0 so that the driver auto falls into video1

***EDIT: Sep 13, 2013 - 3.14AM (crash)***

Logitech C920 in Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10 with kernel 3.11 , 3.5, 3.8, 3.2 all tested. But none works for reliable and stable use.

My system crashed several times and nobody has answer for this to fix.

Latest kernel 3.11 has fixed the xhbc issue which was caused by Logitech C920 which floods the /var/log/syslog but problem is linux kernel disable all USB interfaces if C920 start flooding, which is more worst. I have been testing this camera since kernel 3.2 till 3.11 still no improvement.

Better to find another camera and forget the trust with Logitech for Linux compatibility.

Comment: Looks like this webcam isn't supported on linux: http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28817 .Even the support from Logitech said so: "The C920 webcam is not supported on Ubuntu, so we cannot provide a compliant driver nor a  patch."

Comment: But they supported C910, which worked fine, and now C920 release, they removed Linux? Is it not insulting Linux always? Why would people not release Linux drivers?

Comment: @ThiagoPonte Please post this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @YumYumYum This is a Q&A site, and as such, the comment area is not suitable for extended discussion. You may use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) or the [Ubuntu forums](http://www.ubuntuforums.org) for such purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this webcam isn't supported on linux: [Link](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28817).

Even the support from Logitech said so:

```
"The C920 webcam is not supported on Ubuntu, so we cannot provide a compliant driver nor a patch."
```

Comment: interesting thing is that until 12.04 it worked like a charm.. This webcam works perfectly on 11.04, on straight debian and on crunchbang. Something changed with 12.04 that broke it in this way,.

Comment: You should add a regression bug at launchpad.

Comment: Note that, if Logitech says it's 'not supported on Ubuntu', it means exactly this: *Logitech* isn't going to lift a finger to make the webcam work properly on Ubuntu. 'Not supported' doesn't mean 'it doesn't work' or 'it shouldn't work'. For instance, the UVC developers [know (or believe) that the C920 works without issues with uvcvideo](http://sourceforge.net/p/linux-uvc/mailman/linux-uvc-devel/thread/CAFLt3phFcAnTF25xrV2XUATs9dETv9pFtNZoY3sLgxLUA7j7ug@mail.gmail.com/).